# How to Get the SQLite column _id value for the list item clicked in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I have an activity which show a list. The list is populated from data taken from a sqlite database. I'm using a simpleCursorAdapter. When an item in the list is clicked I want go to another activity page to show more details about the list item clicked. For that I need the _id(primary key) of the clicked list item which is given in the database,  so that I can query the database with that id and show more details in the next activity that loads when user clicks the list item.By using onItemClickListener, How to do this??? I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set that id as ID for list item. so when ever listitem clicks get ID of that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Id with an intent to the next activity:

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, your_next_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", id);
            startActivity(intent);
```

### Then get the value inside the next activity (EDIT):

```
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         int id= intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
```

Then You have the ID and You can query the database:

```
        Cursor c = yourDBHelper.getAllDetailsMethod(); //method inside Your db-helper that gives You the cursor
        int rows = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

            int db_id = c.getInt(0) //this belongs to the place where Your id is inside the db

           if(db_id==id){
               //here You can get all details you need

             break;//stop quering
           }else{

              c.moveToNext();
            }

        }
```

But to give You a good solution it will be good if You show us what You have done until now.

Comment: By using this method when I try to see the value of id in the next activity using a Log("IDGot",id) message , it shows as 0. Why is that?? The value set for the id at the previous activity was 4. I saw that by a Log message. Why is the id value is not shown in the next activity?

Comment: I have changed the catch value method. Try it with Intent intent = getInten(); int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID",0); Where 0 is the defautl value if nothing could passed. Sometimes I had the same problems like You desribed, don´t know why. But with this version I always get the value.

Answer (score 3):

Set _id(primary key) as ID for list item:Adapter of data

Adapter:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;//you can return your ID
}
```

Activity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //id == getItemId(int position);
        }
    });
```

also  do:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //listView.getAdapter().getItem(position) -> getId;
        }
    });
```